# Java PDF document margins are overlapped when content is to large

Tags: java, image-processing, itext, document

I'm converting an image to a pdf document by using iText.
I'm having trouble when I give the image a custom size that's bigger then the document itself.

Before I do `doc.open()`, I set the margins like this 
`doc.setMargins(marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom);`

When I use my `fit` method, this works like a charm:

```
// scale
scaledAwtImage = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, bufferedImageType);
// instantiate
image = instantiateImage(awtImage, scaledAwtImage, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
setAutoRotate(image);
// scaleWithMargins
float targetWidth = doc.getPageSize().getWidth() - mmToUnit(Float.parseFloat(marginLeft) + Float.parseFloat(marginRight));
float targetHeight = doc.getPageSize().getHeight() - mmToUnit(Float.parseFloat(marginBottom) + Float.parseFloat(marginTop));
image.scaleToFit(targetWidth, targetHeight);
```

Probably because of `image.scaleToFit()`. The following is the code I'm having trouble with. As you can see the **right margin** will get overwritten by the image. I can't use `image.scaleToFit()` here because I want to keep the custom sizes. Anyone got an idea?

```
// printWidth
if(printWidth != null && !printWidth.isEmpty() ){
   scaledWidth = (int) mmToUnit(printWidth);
}
// printHeight
if(printHeight != null && !printHeight.isEmpty() ){
   scaledHeight = (int) mmToUnit(printHeight);
}
scaledAwtImage = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, bufferedImageType);
//instantiate
image = instantiateImage(awtImage,scaledAwtImage, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Forgot to post my `instantiateImage()` method for more information.

```
private Image instantiateImage(BufferedImage awtImage, BufferedImage scaledAwtImage, int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight) throws IOException, BadElementException {
 Graphics2D g = scaledAwtImage.createGraphics();
 g.drawImage(awtImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null);
 g.dispose();

 ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ImageIO.write(scaledAwtImage, "jpeg", bout);
 byte[] imageBytes = bout.toByteArray();

 Image image = Image.getInstance(imageBytes);
 return image;
}
```

Comment: You say you *"want to keep the custom sizes"*. If these custom sizes are too large for the document body area, you get into the margins. The only option I see is to enlarge the document body area, e.g. by using smaller margins or a wider page format (e.g. landscape instead of portrait, or actually larger).

Comment: So it is not possible to cut off the image with the size of the margin?

Comment: You can cut it of, but then it does not have the custom size anymore because, well, because it's cut off.

Comment: For printing purposes (that's what the code is made for) I need to force those margins. It sounds stupid, but the analysis says this is required :-)

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you actually want. Your question to me sounds like you want to scale an image to some custom size and as such draw it completely on a PDF page without it overdrawing margin areas. Now you talk about cutting off. This sounds like you do not want to draw it completely but only a subsection of it. Thus your question actually is how to draw only part of an image (and you should still clarify which parts of the image you want to have cut off), isn't it?.

Comment: Maybe I was not specific enough, I do not want that the picture fits on the document page. I want that the picture respects the margins of the document, but that the actual size (spreadout/zoomin/...) stays the way it is. So yes, "cutting of" the margins from the picture, but it keeps his sizes even if they are to big for A5, A4, A3,..

Comment: I had a quick chat with the analyst, I convinced him to enforce the image width/height to be maximum the size of the document. So my problem is solved actually

Comment: First off, yes, sensible input for your code is the best option to start with. But there also are options to cut off. The best one would be to actually cut off *before* generating an iText `Image`, i.e. already in `instantiateImage` which would need an additional parameter for the text body width; cutting off here would prevent the cut off part from being part of the final PDF, keeping it smaller. Another option would be to add a clip path to the pages to prevent anything from flowing into the margins, not only the images. Another option is to overdraw the margins with white in the end.

Comment: It's always a good idea to go back to the analyst and have a chat with him/her if the requirements are unclear. We're not used to saying that as an answer, most of us often rush in to give the best possible technical answer, but as you have shown, that is sometimes not needed. :)